# What version of adobe flash player should i download for the latest linux?

Tags: adobe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

yum for Linux

target for other Linux

rpm for other Linux

apt for Ubuntu 10/04+

i don't have a clue what is going on

Comment: If you aren't on Ubuntu( You don;'t specifically state you are), then this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't download anything. Just use the search function in the Software Center to search for Adobe Flash, it will do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses the Apt system, so get that one.