# Is there no support for microphone recording in Flash Player for linux?

Tags: apt, flash

Is there no support for microphone recording in Flash Player for Linux?
My microphone works fine with Skype. Why is Adobe FlashPlayer unable to use it? Is there no support from Adobe?

Also: My installed version is from Abobe's .tar.gz. I tried to update Flash player using the "APT for Ubuntu" option, but I got:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.243-0precise1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.243-0precise1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
```

what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Flash Player for Linux is at version `11.2.202.261`, while you've been trying to install an older version. Either use the Software Center to install it, or run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

In case you wish to use the Flash Player provided by the Ubuntu partner repository, remove the tar.gz installation first. There is no way to update it, and the two will not work together.

- [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

As for the microphone problem, you should ask Adobe, if there "no support from Adobe".

Answer (score 0):

That file doesn't exist anymore, you need to run `sudo apt-get update` then try again. This will tell `apt` the name of the new version to get.

Answer (score 0):

The microphone recording with Flash didn't work on Firefox, but did work for me when I switched to Chrome. Firefox seems to be particularly problem-prone with Flash.