# Adobe Flash installation help

Tags: installation, flash, adobe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

So I'm trying to install adobe flash and I'm quite new at all this. I've googled around but i can't find any sources that have worked. Right now im at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java and when i click install links i get sent to an error page that says "Firefox can't find the file at apt://openjdk-7-jre." so what do i do?

Comment: You are trying to install Flash, but you were at the Java installation page.

Answer (score 0):

Go here http://smashingweb.info/install-flash-player-on-ubuntu-12-04/ or goto the software center and install the restricted extras

Answer (score 0):

To install Adobe flash, simply write:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

in your terminal.

If you were about to install Java (seems your mixing both up), write

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```