# is there a way to get Flash 11 on ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: flash

I am trying to play my games but not being able to play all of them because of no flash 11. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: What version of flash have you installed?

Comment: I have no idea what flash is installed but i am currently using Google Chrome.

Comment: I looked at that and i don't understand it because its in a different version i looked at my app store and nothing recognizable i then try to search for flash plug ins and nothing came up that was useful.n

Comment: I have found out i have the update installed but it is only 9 i think.

Comment: I would show you guys pictures but my print screen don't even work lol

Comment: Follow this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/65002/44179

Answer (score 2):

You can install google chrome from [there website.](http://www.google.com/chrome) Be sure to select the `.deb` version. It comes with pepperflash pre-installed which is flash version 11.

Comment: well im using Google Chrome.

Comment: and how do i install Google PPA? I am new to using programming.

Comment: @Alvar Untrue! Perhaps you are confused with Chromium (no pepper).

Comment: @Alvar yes 100% sure. You can't even install another version of Flash easily because Google Chrome does not use the old API the Flash version of Linux provides. There are so many fairy tales on Flash on Linux I should write a page about that.

Comment: @gertvdijk Do it! write a page before we forget about it! (I'm definitely php damaged, typing $ instead of @...

Comment: So whats a PPA? or API? i am really new to this because i have no idea what u guys talking about and i'm trying to keep up.