# After downloading a program file from the internet how do you install it?

Tags: installation, flash, downloads

I have downloaded Flash Player 11.5.0 into my Downloads. How do I install it? It is a tar.gz file. Please easy steps through the terminal. I am new to Linux, and want to learn more about it.

Comment: Hi! Although this doesn't answer your question, just fyi. On most GNU/Linux distributions there are so called "software repositories", and whenever a program is available in them, it's preferred to install it from there. On Ubuntu this means, that the recommended way to install software is to use Software Center, Synaptic, apt-get, muon or any other package manager frontend that uses the official Ubuntu repos. Search for flash in Software Center, there is a program named "flashplugin-installer" available.

Comment: i installed the flash program but it keeps saying my flash player needs to be upgraded. i cant use my webcam on the internet and i cant play the games i want to on my sites because it is saying i need to upgrade my flash...

Comment: It isnt in the software center. they just got flash player plug in

Answer (score 0):

Try using google-chrome. It comes with Flash 11.8.800.* Flash support voor linux is till 11.2. I hope this will work for you.

To install Google Chrome go to: https://www.google.com/intl/nl/chrome/browser/ press the download button and download the .deb file either the 32 bit or 64 bit depending on your system. After you downloaded it dubble click on it. The installation will begin(If i'm right the software center will open and install it). After it's done go to your dash and search for Google Chrome. Launch it and test if your problem if fixed.

Comment: I use Chrome. I need Flash 11.5.0 i will try the Manuel way

Comment: Remember when you're using google chrome you need to go to chrome://plugins to disable the newer flash and enable the older one.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: While you've other versions of flash installed. Open your browser and type in your searchbar chrome://plugins. This wil open a list with plugins. in the upper right corner you'll see details. click on it and the plugin list wil expand. Search for Adobe Flash and you'll probably see 2 of more. If you desire to use flash 11.5 disable the other one with pressing on Disable.

I hope this is understandable enough though i aren't a native english speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this link](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/06/how-to-install-flash-player-11-manually.html?m=1). It work with me. The same exact problem cause by protected flash content. This is how to install Adobe Flash Plugin for Firefox:

1. Go to this page and select the option .tar.gz for other Linux. Download the file.
2. Unpack the plugin tar.gz and copy the files to the appropriate location.
3. Save the plugin tar.gz locally and note the location the file was saved to.
4. Launch terminal and change directories to the location the file was saved to.
5. Unpack the tar.gz file. Once unpacked you will see the following:

   ```
   libflashplayer.so 
   /usr
   ```
6. Identify the location of the browser plugins directory, based on your Linux distribution and Firefox version.(Usually it is `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`)
7. Copy `libflashplayer.so` to the appropriate browser plugins directory. At the prompt type:
8. `cp libflashlayer.so <BrowserPluginsLocation>`
   Copy the Flash Player Local Settings configurations files to the /usr directory. At the prompt type:

   ```
   sudo cp -r usr/* /usr
   ```
9. Now restart your browser.

[How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)
Answers by IgnitE