# how can i install adobe flash player 11.tar.gz file on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: flash, adobe

I'm a new user of linux and intalled ubuntu 13.04 and i don't know how to install tar.gz file there. I want to install adobe flash player to play videos on firefox browser. Please give me solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install the tar.gz file.

Following the instructions from [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player) (in a nutshell search and install flash from the Software Centre).

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to install it from the software center. Though I think right now my chrome tells me I need a newer version to watch hulu but firefox doesn't...

to install from the tar.gz you need to untar it first, and follow whatever directions might be in a README or INSTALL file inside
`tar xzvf adobe_flash.tar.gz` or whatever the file is called, then `cd adobe_flash` and follow the instructions. It's usually pretty annoying since you might need to put certain files in special places for each of your browsers... Like I said software center is the easiest.