# Cant watch videos on Browser : Flash Player not installed

Tags: firefox, video, flash, chromium

I have a Toshiba Satellite c655 and have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on it.

I cant watch videos or basically do anything that requires Flash Player. I was able to on the previous version I had of Ubuntu but since I upgraded I haven't been able to.

I've tried uninstalling and installing again using

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

but hasn't fixed the issue.

I'm kind of new to Ubuntu and I think maybe I'm missing something in the process

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

Please ensure that you have latest version of Mozilla Firefox running.

There are multiple ways to get Flash plugin installed on Firefox.

1. You can go to Software Centre > search for Flash > select the second entry on the page which is 64 bit Flash version.
2. Go to Youtube in Firefox and run any video. It will prompt you to *Install missing plug-in* since you do not yet have Flash plugin installed. Click the prompt and follow its process to enable Flash in Firefox.
3. Go to terminal and run this command. It will fetch Flash and other miscellaneous plug-ins for Ubuntu.

   `$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

**Note :** For details of the above methods, you may refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/65002/212399).

---

If the above two methods do not render satisfactory result for you, you can follow following instructions for manual installation of Flash.

**Manual Installation :**

There is a procedure of Manual Installation of Adobe Flash Player on Ubuntu, by following these steps :

1. Open http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/
2. Choose Linux 32-bit or 64 bit (depending on your OS architecture) on Step 1
3. Choose Flash Player 11.2 (tar.gz) on Step 2 and download the file.
4. Once download is complete, right click on the flie (tar.gz) and click on "Extract here".
5. Launch Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
6. Go to that location where you extracted the file.
7. Run this command :

   `$ sudo mv libflashplayer.so \/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins`
8. Launch Mozilla Firefox and check do you have Adobe Flash Player

Credit goes to Vikram on [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1066869).