# Adobe Flash not working in Firefox but in Chrome

Tags: firefox, flash

After installing Flash using terminal and Manually.Flash is not working in Firefox but is working correctly in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome uses a different embedded version called "Pepper Flash". From where and how did you install Flash? Also, look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player).

Comment: Exactly how flash doesn't work and did you installed flash?

Comment: to use pepper plugin in firefox check out this https://github.com/i-rinat/freshplayerplugin

Answer (score -1):

Open Ubuntu Software Center > Click on the "down" arrow next to "All Software"> Click on "Canonical Partner". From there Select "KDE control panel Adobe Flash Player plug-in version 11" You will have to uninstall any previous adobe flash. I was having the same problem that you were having with Firefox while using Ubuntu 14.04 as well.