# How to install adobe flash player for embedded Steam browser (Garry's Mod Cinema gamemode)

Tags: steam, adobe

I have tried to do .rpm and .tar.gz and nearly threw my linux out the window. Any other way?

Comment: did you take a look at this http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html

Comment: Have you tried: [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player). Ubuntu needs debian (`.deb`) packages - rpm packages are for [RPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) based systems (Fedora, CentOS, Scientific Linux, RedHat itself, etc)

Answer (score 1):

This is a side-effect of 32bit Steam needing 32bit Flash. If you're on a 64bit install, you're most likely only going to have 64bit copies of Flash installed. You're not the first person to hit this problem though and [Valve has already published a guide on how to fix it](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1493-GHZB-7612).

The short of it is you create a plugins directory under your Steam dir (with `mkdir -p ~/.steam/bin/plugins`, if you like) and then copy the downloaded 32bit `libflashplayer.so` into it. Restart Steam and you should be good.