# Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available

Tags: software-center, authentication, policy

I'm trying to install flash via the software center and I get this error :

```
"Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not 
available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  
':1.51'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages"
```

I checked the startup applications and found that the policy kit authentication agent was checked.

I then tried to use  `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`

and received this error message:

```
(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:25835): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **:  
Unable to determine the session we are in: No session for pid 25835
```

The error appears to be avoided by running software center in root mode by using

```
gksu software-center
```

or by installing it via command mode e.g. sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer

Comment: Does apt-get work for you?

Comment: I was able to preform sudo apt-get update

Comment: N.B. you can install flash and other things with `apt-get` instead of using the Software center: http://askubuntu.com/a/33134/178596

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PolicyKit seems to be installed and apt-get is working, try the following command

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
```

Comment: The command worked fine still receiving same error although i can get the software center to run fine by using "gksu software-center"

Comment: For the time being, you can install flash using `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: `gksu software-center` hangs for me

Answer (score 0):

I came across this solution on http://looselytyped.blogspot.com/2013/04/making-ubuntu-software-center-work-with.html

Give the following a try:

```
sudo apt-get install polkit-kde-1
```

You might need to logout or restart for the changes to take effect.