# I need help with this file, i edited it wrong, what do i replace with?

Tags: command-line, files, chromium

What comes after the second `CHROMIUM_FLAGS=` in gedit?

I did the wrong thing when trying to install pepper flash. i went by confusing instructions and now i want to just return this file to normal, i get an error in terminal when i edit it if i dont get it right. here's my file:

```
# Default settings for chromium-browser. This file is sourced by /bin/sh from 
# /usr/bin/chromium-browser 

# Options to pass to chromium-browser 
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="" 

# part for pepperflashplugin-nonfree : begin 

flashso="/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-non... 

if [ -f $flashso ] 
then 
flashversion=`strings $flashso|grep ^LNX|sed -e "s/^LNX //"|sed -e "s/,/./g"` 
CHROMIUM_FLAGS=". /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepfla... 
fi 

# part for pepperflashplugin-nonfree : end 
. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepfla...
```

The file is called `*default` ( in `/etc/chromium-browser`) and the line after `CHROMIUM_FLAGS=` is where i messed up but i saved it without knowing, what goes after?

Comment: By default `/etc/chromium-browser/default` has only the line `CHROMIUM_FLAGS=""` . You have messed it up while editing it.

Comment: It had something there before, i erased it

Comment: is there a way to reset the file?

Comment: Yes, go to the `/etc/chromium-browser` directory, rename the current file as something else than default e.g. `default.bak`, then create a file named `default` having only the line `CHROMIUM_FLAGS=""`

Comment: I cant rename the file, i dont have permission to?

Comment: Use `sudo` at the start i.e. `sudo mv default default.bak`

Comment: ok, i re named default, now how do i save this new one? i opened gedit and typed CHROMIUM_FLAGS="" but i cant save it to the same folder. perms again o-o'

Comment: use `sudo` again....as this directory is owned by root..you need to impersonate root by using `sudo` to create a file or edit a file..open the file like `sudo gedit default`

Comment: It saved. should i worry about the error in terminal?:

Comment: (gedit:9549): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: Nope, you don't need to worry....check now....

Comment: I'm still having problems with Chromium, Google Hangouts keeps crashing and when i go to a site like Gmail the Aww Snap! error page pops up no matter how many times i refresh. Should I make a new post for that?

Comment: Oh... now YouTube just started too. Aww Snap error page

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: For some reason the error stopped with YouTube, but with Gmail the blue screen pops up that says:

Comment: Aww Snap! Something went wrong wile displaying this webpage. To continue reload or go to another webpage.

Comment: Disable pepper flash or any incompatible plugin, Restart the computer and then check..

Comment: Same is happening but there is no flash player now in plugins

Comment: Ok..i think some other configuration files also get edited in the process causing this not to be fixed.....Now one solution to purge the browser first and then install again..sync your bookmarks and other stuffs.....then run `sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser && sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Comment: It doesnt seem to have changed... I purged then installed and even restarted my computer after :(

Comment: Should I have some type of flash player in plugins? Because since i tinkered with pepper then removed it there is no longer a flash player in my plugin list.

Comment: yes, you need to have a flash plugin..you can install adobe flash plugin by `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

Comment: Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate

Comment: That's what i got

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: Or you can check this post http://askubuntu.com/q/11/216503

Comment: No change, and after i installed it it still didnt show in my plugin list for Chromium

Comment: Now youtube and other google sites still have earlier problem?

Comment: Yes. it seems to be only some Youtube videos but it's constant with google sites and bing

Comment: by bing i mean the hompage

Comment: Ok..i think thats need a in depth diagnosis of chromium....i am not very good at in depth analysis of browsers or most GUI tools..i am gonna put the steps i mentioned earlier as an answer as those solved the initial query....please ask the current chromium status as a new question, somebody with a deep knowledge on that will surely help you....

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your time. I appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem..i have given the answer to the initial issue..please select it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer so that the initial problem can be marked as solved....Also ask a new question regarding the current issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go back to the default state by removing changes made to the file `/etc/chromium-browser/default`.

If you want to keep the current file `/etc/chromium-browser/default`, then rename the file as something else than default e.g. `default.bak`. Now create a file named `default` having nothing or only the line `CHROMIUM_FLAGS=""`.

To summarize:

```
sudo mv /etc/chromium-browser/default /etc/chromium-browser/default.bak
echo 'CHROMIUM_FLAGS=""' | sudo tee -a /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

Comment: Elegant solution...  Upvoted!  ;-)