# Not able to see videos in youtube or fb

Tags: 14.04

Not able to see videos in youtube or fb.I am getting the following error.

Failed to load "libpepflashplayer.so"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install flash player. One option is to go through the official download [site](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) or follow this post instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263239/install-flash-player-on-ubuntu-14-04). Download it and install it. An alternative is to install pipelight.

> Pipelight is project that brings Silverlight, Flash etc to any Linux browser that supports the Netscape Plugin API. Using it, you can use services that require Silverlight, such as Netflix, in native Linux web browsers like Firefox, Chrome or Midori.

[Tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html) on Pipelight.

1) Optional update your system

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

2) Remove older pipelight

```
sudo apt-get remove pipelight
```

3) Add the repository and install pipelight

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

4) Finally enable flash

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable flash
```

5) Check the system (optional)

```
pipelight-plugin --system-check
```

6) Check for other plugins from pipelight

```
pipelight-plugin --help
```