# Flash and twitch.tv crashing

Tags: flash, streaming

I have recently installed Ubuntu and updated it to 14.04 LTS. I also installed Ubuntu restricted extras and youtube seemed to be working fine but when I tried to watch [twitch.tv](http://twitch.tv/), the Mozilla Firefox flash plug-in was crashing.

It works for a few minutes when watching a stream and then crashes. I tried downloading the Linux Adobe Flash Player from the Adobe website and ran this command

```
tar -xvf install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

I saw that someone on Youtube fixed it in this way but I still get the same problem of Flash crashing after a few minutes.

I'm still new to Ubuntu so if you know what is wrong can you go slow explaining any procedure to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

Comment: @Knocko Try my updated answer!

Answer (score 2):

Adobe's current Flash player for linux is extremely old.  The only way to get an up to date version is to use [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) which has a Pepper implementation of Flash (PepperFlash). So I recommend you install [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html).

To install Chrome:

1. Go to https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html
2. Click the blue button that says "Download Chrome." This will bring up a menu asking you to select the package you want to download.
3. Select either the 32 bit .deb or 64 bit .deb depending on you computer's architecture. Most modern computers are 64 bit, but it's not a bad idea to double check.
4. Then, click "Accept and Install". The download will start.
5. Once the download finishes, open the file. This should bring up Software Centre.
6. Click the install button.

Alternatively, you can just use the HTML5 player by installing [this GreaseMonkey script](https://www.reddit.com/r/Twitch/comments/3pip76/userscript_to_use_full_html5_on_twitchtv/)

Comment: While Adobe Flash for Mozilla on Linux is old, it is *not unsupported* since Adobe still releases security patches which Canonical distributes through the partner repository. In my experience many web sites are fine with Flash Player 11 – especially when they just play back videos.

Comment: @DavidFoerster In my experience, Flash Player 11 can't handle live streams. I've had issues using it with Twitch and YouTube live streams, as well as online video chats.

Comment: Twitch.tv still works with Flash Player 11 and Firefox 44 on my system.

Comment: Thank you @Grammargeek ill try that. I checked and my versions are Flash Player 11 and Firefox 44 but there still not working with live streams DavidFoerster