# Problem installing adobe flash player plugin on chromium

Tags: flash, chromium

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I have tried multiple explanations on here but none of them seem to work. I tried out one and figured out it was for Opera and not Chromium and the one on Chromium was outdated and pepperflash couldn't be found because of a 404 error.

I installed adobe and restarted, then I checked my plugins and only the PDF file viewer is there, no flash plugin.

[image: Chromium plug-in page]

Thanks in advance for the help and this is for Chromium Web Browser.

```
$ apt-cache policy adobe-flashplugin
adobe-flashplugin:
Installed: 1:20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Candidate: 1:20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Version table:
 *** 1:20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial/partner amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ file -L /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=5e833404c78369b704ff1b4abd06c7debe3bfb9a, stripped

$ chromium-browser /etc/chromium-browser/default: line 6: /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh: No such file or directory Using PPAPI flash. Created new window in existing browser session.
```

`/etc/chromium-browser/customizations/10-flash` = **333 bytes**

[`dpkg-query -L adobe-flashplugin`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23155608/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player). Yes, it's old but `adobe-flashplugin` now includes Pepper Flash and configuration files for Chromium to pick it up.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I did that earlier and it didn't work. I'm not using Firefox

Comment: It works for Chromium too. It's the exact set-up I'm using. I made no modifications to it. If you provide the output of `apt-cache policy adobe-flashplugin` and `dpkg-query -L adobe-flashplugin`, the content of `/etc/chromium-browser/customizations/10-flash` and a screenshot of the page with the address `chrome://plugins` from inside Chromium, I might be able to figure out what's different or wrong with your set-up.

Comment: @DavidFoerster http://i63.tinypic.com/23uyhoo.png http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=md396t&s=9#.V9HhYh-i48o http://i67.tinypic.com/md396t.png http://i65.tinypic.com/2wp2ot0.png Okay now for some reason in the last screenshot Flash is now there but it was unchecked, screenshot is after i checked it and ran a flash program. The program worked. Not sure what changed after those commands I ran but any idea why the 3rd command wouldn't work? Is that an issue?

Comment: The output of `chromium & { sleep 1; tr '\0' ' ' < /proc/$!/cmdline; echo; }` could be helpful too.

Comment: @DavidFoerster alright I got a lot of replies lol. 1. How do I share the .txt files with you? 2. The chromium line of code said. `code [1] 4878 chromium: command not found [1]+ Exit 127   chromium 0: command not found bash: /proc/4878/cmdline: No such file or directory code`

Comment: When I asked for the output of a command most recently, that should have been `chromium-browser & { sleep 1; tr '\0' ' ' < /proc/$!/cmdline; echo; }`. That was a copy&paste mistake on my end. I could also use the output of `file -L /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Alright well, I try to output the ``chromium-browser`` to a .txt file but the file is blank and the terminal shows the output. Same with the ``dpkg-query``

Comment: @DavidFoerster do you get a notification when I edit? I got it to work with ``sudo`` in front of the command. I shared the file in the OP

Comment: No, edits don't incur notifications. Only comments do. Thanks for all the info. So far so good. Could you please put file or program output listings either directly into your question or use a hoster that doesn't require me to give them my e-mail address? Any pastie service like https://paste.ubuntu.com/ should be fine. What's the output of `chromium-browser` when you start it in a terminal?

Comment: @DavidFoerster okay I updated with a new file using paste.ubuntu.com