# Porblem with Flash player under Ubuntu 16 LTS

Tags: firefox, flash, crash

I'm preparing for CCNA from netacad website.
Perhaps some of you have seen the platform, It offers a text materials next to picture or flash player objects.
The flash animations work well, but I notice a problem in the console simulator.
In chrome, all what I need is to left-click next to prompt (#) in order to write commands.
In Firefox, left-click doesn't work, I have to use right-click and the simulator ofter crash after some clicks, as you can see in pictures.

Packages I use :

```
dpkg --list|grep -i 'firefox\|flash'

ii  firefox                                    56.0+build6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2                 amd64        Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla
ii  firefox-locale-en                          56.0+build6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2                 amd64        English language pack for Firefox
ii  flashplugin-installer                      27.0.0.183ubuntu0.16.04.1                    amd64        Adobe Flash Player plugin installer
ii  unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks               0.1+13.10.20130809.1-0ubuntu1                all          Firefox bookmarks scope for Unity
ii  xul-ext-ubufox                             3.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                         all          Ubuntu modifications for Firefox
```

[Cisco simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjANP.png)
[Flash player crashed !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NkIr.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

Comment: The `flashplugin-installer` package is obsolete, and you should instead be using `adobe-flashplugin` package. However, note that Google includes their own version of Flash inside the Chrome browser.

Comment: Further on dobey's comment, this may also be a Flash version issue as well since, as you may know, Adobe no longer supports Linux for Flash after 11.2.202.350.

Comment: @dobey - he has flash installed and running, but it crashes. So not a dupe of that question, but maybe another.

Comment: @ravery It's a duplicate because the question clearly shows the wrong package installed.

Comment: @P05TMAN You certainly meant "Flash for Linux" and not the other way around... ;) In any case, not applicable. The `adobe-flashplugin` package mentioned above provides a fairly updated Flash version for browsers other than Chrome which already has it. Currently running version 27.0.0.183 in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @dobey -- chrome v60 and newer no longer contains pepperflash. Coincidentally this change occured when adobe released the new flashplayer for linux.

Comment: I installed `adobe-flashplugin` but the problem persists.

Comment: @dobey: You are wrong as regards `flashplugin-installer`. That package is just as valid as `adobe-flashplugin`, and provides the very same plugin for Firefox. Please read [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) for more info.

Comment: @jeff I think you need to report it to the web site in question then, and perhaps Adobe, as it's a bug with the flash code.

Comment: This is a long shot, but installing the [browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html#browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash) package may be worth a try.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson That gives a better results, I needed to install `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`. Now, it crashes when I use right-click.

Comment: @jeff: It surprises me that you needed to install `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`. Don't you have `xenial-updates` enabled in _Software & Updates / Updates_? If you haven't, you really should enable it.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson It's enabled !

Comment: @jeff: Then is your system updated (`sudo apt update`)? Asking because the version of `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` in `xenial-updates`does not depend on or recommend `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`. (The version in `xenial-release` does.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson before adding `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`, the browser showed an error message a message about loading `libpepflashplayer.so` instead of the flash.

Comment: @jeff: Loading `libpepflashplayer.so` instead of `libflashplayer.so` is the whole point of `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash`. Maybe a browser restart or relogin/reboot would have made that message disappear. Since you have `adobe-flashplugin` installed, `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` ought to be redundant. Anyway, I'm glad it seemed to help.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I recently updated my browser from 56 to 57. Now, it uses version `27.0.0.187` and works perfectly.

Comment: @jeff: Would be good if you could post the solution as an answer. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved after installing the latest version of Firefox `57` (released during the discussion).