# How to get Flash to work on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player), says that Flash is available in the software center, but it is not for me at least. I tried downloading from their [site](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/); first I tried APT which failed with the message "unknown channel: artful-partner." I also tried downloading the tar.gz - first I followed the instructions on their website and the I tried just extracting everything to `~/.mozilla/extensions`. Nothing worked.

Comment: I followed the instructions for activating the artful-partner repository but when I type `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin` it says that the package is not available.

Comment: You need to update the package system first (`sudo apt update`). OTOH, for Firefox `flashplugin-installer` ought to be sufficient.

Comment: I updated and tried to reinstall but the package was already installed. Crunchyroll is the website that I want to use that requires flash and is how I've been testing whether or not the installation is successful.

Comment: Well, that's a paid service. You'd better start with the page I suggested in my comment on N0rbert's answer. Doing so will tell you if Firefox is seeing Flash Player.

Comment: I tried the instructions on the page you linked. Didn't work. I've installed google chrome which downloaded flash by itself and it works. So my problem doesn't really exist anymore even though neither of your solutions worked for some reason :/

Answer (score 0):

You can install Adobe Flash Player with `apt-get`:

`sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`.

Comment: Ran this and restarted firefox but it did not work.

Comment: @EbenCowley: How did you determine that "it did not work"? Does [this page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/) show the Flash Player version?